# Can't determine relationships between the fields

Tags: powerbi, relationship, powerbi-desktop

I've imported three tables into Power BI using a REST API, have added relationships between them, and am now trying to add fields from the various tables to a table on the canvas. The table names (from a Human Resources database) are named Employees, Job History, and Salary History.

Employees is joined to Job History using EmployeeID as a 1:Many relationship, and also to Salary History using EmployeeID on a 1:Many relationship.

I can add fields from the Employee table and EITHER the Salary History OR the Job History table to the table on the report canvas. However, if I try to add fields from all three tables, I'm seeing the error 'Can't display the data because Power BI can't determine the relationship between two or more fields'.

Could anyone advise where I'm going wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a model like in this picture:
[image]

The way PBI filters work is: The **1:** side table filters the **N:** side table. Filters propagate that way. So in this case, you can filter JobHistory with data from Employees, and SalaryHistory with data from Employees. But the 2 fact tables can't relate because the filters don't propagate that way.

Look into DAX measures like RELATED(), RELATEDTABLE() and USERELATIONSHIP() that might work for you.

Without that, I don't think you can use data from the 3 tables, since you have a model with 2 Fact Tables.

Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, the comment entry timed out: Apologies if I'm missing something fundamental, but I'm more used to writing SQL and then using the statement in Power BI, than building relationships directly in Power BI. Can you tell me how, in Power BI, I would reproduce the joins: "Select * from Employees E Join JobHistory JH on JH.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID Join SalaryHistory SH on SH.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID" ?

Comment: Joins are better on the SQL side (in power query it takes a really long time to join tables), so I'd recommend you writing that query when you connect to your database and you get that data exactly (When connecting to SQL Server Database, click on Advanced Options and write your query). Then just import the other tables you need so you can implement the relationships.
EDIT: keep in mind that DAX is really handy to know if you're going to use Power BI, and ca really help you that kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks - Unfortunately I'm connecting to a REST API this time, and bringing in each of the tables with one URL per table. Bottom line is that I need to learn more about both DAX, and Power BI as a whole. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see. You need to join in Power Query or DAX then. Here is an article that helped me when I did it: https://www.antaresanalytics.net/post/2018/11/03/power-bi-ultimate-guide-to-joining-tables